# reactjs - how to render images from a json blob

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I am pushing json data into a react component. I've tried to add cost image = require(json.image) inside the loop, but its not a valid procedure. Require doesn't metabolise the dynamic path -- and import is not valid at the child level

Answer (score 4):

Store the `json` in the `state` or a `prop` and then use it to render the image

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(json.image);
```

EDIT: If `json.image` is file data then you have to convert to a `blob`

```
var binaryData = []; 
binaryData.push(data); 
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"}))"
```

Comment: I will try that -- what is this URL.createObjectUrl function?

Comment: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided

Comment: "I experienced same error, when I passed to createObjectURL raw data:

window.URL.createObjectURL(data)
It has to be Blob or File object, not data itself. This worked for me:

var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(data);
window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"}))"

Comment: ah nothing is working -- I only get luck if the image is hosted externally

Comment: -- but the data would be an image path --

Comment: I fixed it by altering the json path to go straight to the root -- so "/src/img/image.png"